# VueJs NON-SPA Laravel application: autoloading components based on the view

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to figure out how to optimise the size of my javascript file in the non single page laravel application to make sure that only some components, that are required by each view are being registered globally.

I'm compiling everything using `webpack` setup which comes out of the box with `laravel-mix`.

I don't want to compile all of those components into a single file as some of them are only to be used for a single module / view.

Having one instance of Vue, which is bound to the `#app` I would like to find out if there is a way of registering components on demand - i.e. some sort of method that could register it from within blade's view.

Comment: try visit this question,.. maybe it can help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63626792/laravel-vue-non-spa-how-to-split-the-files-for-every-page-for-its-vue-js-compo/63627055?noredirect=1#comment112513413_63627055